# z-index doesn't let you select text

Tags: html, css

I have a  that does the back shading with z-index: 10, and another with z-index: 11 that shows what I want, I have other information on the back page, but the idea is to keep
"main page" -> shadow -> "info I want"

When I open this  with z-index: 11, everything inside looks strange, I can't click on , only on  and I can't select the texts either.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

OBS: The project has bootstrap, a slightly old version like 4 or 3, I don't remember exactly, but for this specific case no bootstrap classes were used, it was done "by hand"

Comment: [`Como começar aqui no Stack Overflow em Português`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/700/como-come%c3%a7ar-aqui-no-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas?cb=1)